# Вырезать из строки все после нужного символа

Tags: php

Строка

```
Параметр|Номинальная мощность котла|14 кВт:20 кВт:30 кВт:40 кВт:50 кВт:65 кВт:80 кВт:97 кВт:150 кВт:200 кВт:250 кВт:300 кВт:400 кВт:500 кВт:600 кВт
```

и допустим после 4 или 6 **:** мне нужно все удалить в строке. Как это можно правильней реализовать ?

Comment: покажите позицию в строке, в которой у вас находится 4, или 6.

Comment: @Эдуард видимо после 4го или 6го двоеточия имелось в виду.

Comment: @teran т.е. в результате должна быть такая строка _(или немного длиннее)_ `'Параметр|Номинальная мощность котла|14 кВт:20 кВт:30 кВт:40 кВт:'` ?

Comment: @Эдуард да только в конце удалить еще : в последнем элементе

Comment: Есть такая магическая функция в PHP. Называется Split. http://fi2.php.net/manual/ru/function.split.php Читать "Пример #1" до полного понимания.

Comment: @Akina тогда уж http://fi2.php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-split.php, а то вашей нет в пхп 7 и устарела еще в 5.3

Comment: @teran ну просто версию-то товарищ указать постеснялся... а вообще preg_split ему поди сложно, обойдётся и вульгарным http://fi2.php.net/manual/ru/function.explode.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пока писали  люди за что им огромное спасибо сделал сам и на несколько уже строк сразу.Понимаю что код не шикарен.

```
$one_post = $_POST['one'];
$del_number = $_POST['two'];
$one_post = explode(PHP_EOL,$one_post);
foreach ($one_post as $one_post_as){
    $one_post_as = explode(":", $one_post_as);
    array_splice($one_post_as,$del_number);
    $articles[] = $one_post_as;
}
foreach ($articles as $article_as){
    $article_as = implode(':',$article_as);

    $article_as_As[] = $article_as;
}
$article_as_As = implode(PHP_EOL,$article_as_As);
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно написать пользовательскую функцию, которая будет принимать два параметра: первый - исходная строка, второй - число повторов для блоков, в которых указана мощность:

```
function replace_string($str, $int = 4) {
    $str = preg_replace("~([^:]+(?:\d+\s\D+:){{$int}}).*~", '$1', $str);
    return rtrim($str, ':');
}
```

Использование:

```
$str = 'Параметр|Номинальная мощность котла|14 кВт:20 кВт:30 кВт:40 кВт:50 кВт:65 кВт:80 кВт:97 кВт:150 кВт:200 кВт:250 кВт:300 кВт:400 кВт:500 кВт:600 кВт';

// с параметром по умолчанию
echo replace_string($str);

// с двумя параметрами
echo replace_string($str, 6);
```

Результаты:

```
Параметр|Номинальная мощность котла|14 кВт:20 кВт:30 кВт:40 кВт
Параметр|Номинальная мощность котла|14 кВт:20 кВт:30 кВт:40 кВт:50 кВт:65 кВт
```